# Find the probability that the balls will fall into neighboring cells

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics

Two balls are scattered randomly and independently of each other in 4 cells located one after the other in a straight line. Each ball with the same probability of 1/4 hits each cell. Find the probability that the balls will fall into neighboring cells.

In lectures given this solution:

Event A: balls hit neighboring cells divide into as many variants as possible to form pairs of neighboring cells. 3 variants: A = A1 + A2 + A3

A1 is when balls got into #1 and #2

A2 is #2 and #3

A3 is #3 and #4

Every Ai equals $\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} \times 2 = \frac{1}{8}$ And the answer is $\frac{3}{8}$

I can't understand why we get these $\frac{1}{8}$ and 2, can you explain me how we get it?

Comment: Let one of the balls be red and the other blue. The probability that the red ball arrives in cell 1 and the blue in cell 2 equals $1/4\times 1/4$. This is also the probability that this happens with switched colors so needs to be multiplied by 2 to get the probability that cells 1 and 2 will be occupied by neighboring balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of a ball to fall in any box is $\frac{1}{4}$.
Let:

- X be event that Ball 1 falls into box #1
- Y be the event that Ball 2 falls into box #2

$P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y) = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4}$ This is because the events X and Y are independent, the fact that a ball is landing in a box does not influence the other ball from landing in any box available.

The reason you multiply by 2 is the fact that the balls are undistinguishable. This means that you don't care which ball goes in box 1 and which goes in box 2. So for A1 you can the following combinations:

- Ball 1 in Box #1 and Ball 2 in Box #2 OR
- Ball 2 in Box #1 and Ball 1 in Box #2

Comment: ar, firstly i didn't catch the moment with undistinguishability now I got it, thanks so much :>

Comment: You're welcome.